# Removing JSESSIONID httponly vulnerability from karaf 4 pax-jetty

Tags: java, spring-mvc, security, jetty, karaf

I am trying to remove the httponly cookie vulnerability from a karaf server running an embedded jetty. The java app is spring MVC based using spring security 3.2.10.RELEASE. I have tried  a few different thing without success.

First try  I added the following on the web.xml with no sucess

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">


    <session-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> <!-- in minutes -->
        <cookie-config>
            <secure>true</secure>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <!-- Spring Config Files -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/webmodule-mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>blueprintLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.aries.blueprint.web.BlueprintContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener-->


    <!-- Spring MVC WEB Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webmodule-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Second try I added the following code on the WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml with no sucess.

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="sessionHandler">
        <Get name="sessionManager">
            <Set name="httpOnly" type="boolean">true</Set>
            <Set name="secureCookies" type="boolean">true</Set>
        </Get>
    </Get>
</Configure>
```

Third try I added  the following code on the /etc/jetty.xml on the karaf directory.

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="sessionHandler">
        <Get name="sessionManager">
            <Set name="httpOnly" type="boolean">true</Set>
            <Set name="secureCookies" type="boolean">true</Set>
        </Get>
    </Get>
</Configure>
```

On all three attempts jetty seems to be ignoring this configuration since the JSESSIONID cookie still does not appears as secure and httponly.  Can somebody shade some light on the proper way to eliminate this vulnerability from Pax-jetty running on karaf 4?

Thanks

Comment: What version of the servlet spec are you using?  As this ability was only introduced in Servlet 3.0 (older versions of the spec do not support this cookie-config)

Comment: Hello and thanks for your time, I am using servlet 3.0.1

Comment: "Servlet 3.0.1" is not a spec version, that's an artifact version (different things).  Your webapp has a `WEB-INF/web.xml` and that is what specifies the specific version of the servlet spec your webapp is declared as.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I posted the complete the web.xml header.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

Answer (score 3):

After much research I found the solution on the following post from RedHat

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/security_guide/webconsole

Basically the following properties need to be defined on the   /etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg file.

org.ops4j.pax.web.session.cookie.httpOnly=true

org.osgi.service.http.secure.enabled=true

Comment: It's not clear whether this works if jetty is serving http request behind a load-balancer or reverse proxy that handles https